# How to echo WordPress User metadata

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show users that have entered an address in their profile. I'm using this code to show the metadata.

```
 <?php $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user_id){
    print_r(get_user_meta ( $user_id->ID));
    }?>
```

How can echo just the address? I've tried several variations of this and it doesn't work.

```
echo $user_id->dokan_profile_settings[address];
```

This is what the var_dumb looks like.

```
[dokan_profile_settings] => Array ( [0] => a:16:{s:10:"store_name";s:9:"Best Farm";s:9:"store_ppp";i:10;s:7:"address";a:6:{s:8:"street_1";s:16:"1600 valley road";s:8:"street_2";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:8:"richmond";s:3:"zip";s:5:"23231";s:7:"country";s:2:"US";s:5:"state";s:2:"MO";}s:8:"location";s:0:"";s:12:"find_address";s:5:"Dhaka";s:6:"banner";i:0;s:5:"phone";s:0:"";s:10:"show_email";s:2:"no";s:14:"show_more_ptab";s:3:"yes";s:8:"gravatar";i:0;s:10:"enable_tnc";s:3:"off";s:9:"store_tnc";s:0:"";s:16:"dokan_store_time";a:7:{s:6:"sunday";a:3:{s:6:"status";s:5:"close";s:12:"opening_time";s:0:"";s:12:"closing_time";s:0:"";}s:6:"monday";a:3:{s:6:"status";s:5:"close";s:12:"opening_time";s:0:"";s:12:"closing_time";s:0:"";}s:7:"tuesday";a:3:{s:6:"status";s:5:"close";s:12:"opening_time";s:0:"";s:12:"closing_time";s:0:"";}s:9:"wednesday";a:3:{s:6:"status";s:5:"close";s:12:"opening_time";s:0:"";s:12:"closing_time";s:0:"";}s:8:"thursday";a:3:{s:6:"status";s:5:"close";s:12:"opening_time";s:0:"";s:12:"closing_time";s:0:"";}s:6:"friday";a:3:{s:6:"status";s:5:"close";s:12:"opening_time";s:0:"";s:12:"closing_time";s:0:"";}s:8:"saturday";a:3:{s:6:"status";s:5:"close";s:12:"opening_time";s:0:"";s:12:"closing_time";s:0:"";}}s:24:"dokan_store_time_enabled";s:2:"no";s:23:"dokan_store_open_notice";s:0:"";s:24:"dokan_store_close_notice";s:0:"";} ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a gander at the docs for [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/). The third parameter is nice because it causes it to return a single value instead of a (usually 1 element) array. Side note, if you If you need just the `dokan_profile_settings`, you can get that with `get_user_meta( $user_id->ID, 'dokan_profile_settings', true );`. (Another neat thing, with `get_users` you can do `'fields' => 'all_with_meta'` to return all the meta fields as well

The thing about that meta field is that the data is [serialized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). Once you get that variable, regardless of method, you'll need to [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it, if it doesn't get unserialized automatically. WordPress has a handy function called [`maybe_unserialize`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) that works well for fields like this in case the data may or may not have been serialized.

That leads us to something like this:

```
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach( $users as $user ){
    $dokan_profile_settings = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'dokan_profile_settings', true );
    $dokan_profile_settings = maybe_unserialize( $dokan_profile_settings );

    echo $dokan_profile_settings['address'];
}
```

Comment: Xhynk is correct, you need to use the unserialize function to operate on that data. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, I appreciate it. The code you provided is giving me errors.

- Array to string conversion on line 11
- Illegal string offset 'address' on line 11
- Uninitialized string offset: 0 on line 11

line 11 is -

echo $dokan_profile_settings['address'];

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this.

```
<?php $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user_id){
    $dokan_profile_setings = get_user_meta ( $user_id->ID,'dokan_profile_setting', true);
    $address = $dokan_profile_setings['address'];
    echo $address;
}?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code you provided is giving me errors. - Array to string conversion on line 11 - Illegal string offset 'address' on line 11 - Uninitialized string offset: 0 on line 11 line 11 is - $address = $dokan_profile_setings['address'];

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could be helpful for you

`<?php 
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user){
    $dokan_profile_setings = get_user_meta ( $user->ID,'dokan_profile_setting', true);
    $getAddress = $dokan_profile_setings['address'];
    echo $getAddress;
}?>`